# Double hash SHA256 in Python

Tags: python, hash, bitcoin, sha256

Im trying to reproduce the following:

=========================================
 *from Bitcoin Wiki*

**Transaction puzzle**

Transaction '...' is an interesting puzzle.

```
given hash = 6fe28c0ab6f1b372c1a6a246ae63f74f931e8365e15a089c68d6190000000000
```

To spend the transaction you need to come up with some data such that hashing the data twice results in the given hash. The required data happened to be the Genesis block, and the given hash was the genesis block hash

==========================================

genesis = '000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f'

The following function doublehashes input(it works for step 14 in [this example](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5241/20932))

```
def function(input):
    data = input.decode('hex_codec')
    result = binascii.hexlify(hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(data).digest()).digest())
    print result
```

But inputting the genesis hash, it produces the following result:

**string:**
"ae253ca2a54debcac7ecf414f6734f48c56421a08bb59182ff9f39a6fffdb588"

**hex:** 
"61 65 32 35 33 63 61 32 61 35 34 64 65 62 63 61 63 37 65 63 66 34 31 34 66 36 37 33 34 66 34 38 63 35 36 34 32 31 61 30 38 62 62 35 39 31 38 32 66 66 39 66 33 39 61 36 66 66 66 64 62 35 38 38 0d 0a"

I'm obviously doing something wrong but can't seem to figure out what.

---

**ANSWER:** As mentioned by Falsaltru;

The required hash was used earlier to calculate the blockhash, thus why the hash itself was 'not hard to find'.

Comment: Pardon me, OP is fixed now. This didn't cause the isseu however, problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the given hash by reversing the `genesis` (bytes):

```
>>> import binascii                                                                             
>>> genesis = '000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f'
>>> given_hash = '6fe28c0ab6f1b372c1a6a246ae63f74f931e8365e15a089c68d6190000000000'
>>> binascii.unhexlify(given_hash) == binascii.unhexlify(genesis)[::-1]
True
```